# sqlite3 .dump function not saving file

Tags: database, command-line, sqlite, terminal

I am trying to dump a database to a text file, I am using this statement: `.dump | sqlite3 /Users/riceje7/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles/4pixicxh.default/downloads.sqlite | gzip -c >database.dump.gz`. I get a begin transaction and commit statement in the terminal but the file never saves anywhere on my computer. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how i can get this to work?

Comment: I assume you have an "echo" in the front right? Like this:   echo .dump | sqlite3 /Users/riceje7/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles/4pixicxh.default/downloads.sqlite | gzip -c >database.dump.gz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out...the file i was trying to access was a protected file, all i had to do was copy the file to another location and access it there. thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax:

```
sqlite3 /Users/riceje7/Library/Application/Support/Firefox/Profiles/4pixicxh.default/downloads.sqlite .dump | gzip -c >database.dump.gz
```